Delete Method in CRUD operation in Spring Bo
I have been trying CRUD Operation for my spring boot.
I have to delete the row by given name in delete() method. I need some guidance to get this working. I debugged the code but it returns 500 error on Postman.  What did I do wrong?
public String deletedList(String name) {

        List <Grocery> v = rss.findAll();
        
        for(Grocery gig: v) {
            while(gig != null) {
        if(gig.getName().equals(name)) {
        rss.deleteAll();`your text`
        return "success";
    }}
        }
        for(Grocery f : v) {
        if(f.getName() != name) {
            throw new DeleteException("Not Found");
        }}
        return "not found"; 
}


Remove the while loop and replace it with an if condition. and Use rss.delete(grocery) to delete the matched item instead of rss.deleteAll(). This should work as expected.

Maybe you could [edit] your answer and post the corrected code that includes the changes you are describing?
